# Auto cloning a git repository when an new commit

Tags: linux, git, github, google-cloud-platform, debian

How do I auto clone an github repository when an new commit is made to the repository and automatically run the `node .` command.
I have an GCP vm instance running debian linux to host my discord bot, I want it so when I put an commit through to github it automatically downloads that new commit and re runs the `node .` command.
I have done some research into this and I can't find anything that can help me set this up.

Comment: Is this a persistent VM, or do you want to start over every time?

Comment: An persistent VM, when an new commit request is sent to the repo. From either git command line tools or github desktop from my windows machine it re pulls the git by doing `git pull` and runs the code by doing `node .`

Comment: There are several methods to do this. The first part is to set up a GitHub WebHook. That hook calls something via HTTP. That something can be a virtual machine, Cloud Run, etc that then executes commands to pull changes and run whatever commands you need to update the system. This repo has many example commands: https://github.com/runhyve/vm-webhooks There are other techniques such as running a cron script once per day, etc. You must do the research. Post a question once you have a problem.

Comment: If those concepts seem challenging to implement, consider using a CI/CD solution that has everything you need. Many companies offer these features.

Comment: https://beranger.medium.com/automate-deployment-with-google-compute-engine-and-cloud-build-cccd5c3eb93c